# Opencart admin panel not accessible

Tags: ssl, authentication, https, ssl-certificate, opencart

Since I installed a SSL certificate on my website, the admin panel is not accessible.

It´s actually because I cannot click the login button.

https://www.umweltfreunde.com/admin/

Thanks a lot for helping me fix this.

Razvan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because on your site, the base URL is not **https**. Currently it is as in the screenshot below:[image: screenshot]

Please make changes in your admin header file to change the base URL to HTTPS.

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you please accept this as answer!